# JS fiddle code stopped working

Tags: javascript

Getting an error in chrome console about pop up blocker (exception made in chrome settings for jsfiddle) and a totally different error "InvalidAccessError: A parameter or an operation is not supported by the underlying object" in mozilla. This code was working in fiddle and suddenly stopped. Is there some sort of cap or am I overlooking some sort of syntax issue https://jsfiddle.net/3vjru5zp/20/

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Domain (ex. domain.com)" id="input">
<button type="button" id="button">Click Me!</button>

$(document).ready(function() {

 $('#button').click(function(e) {
   var inputvalue = $('#input').val();
   //Opens http www version in new tab
   test = window.open('http://www.' + inputvalue, "test");
   //Opens https www version in new tab
   test2 = window.open('https://www.' + inputvalue, "test2");
   //Opens http non www version in new tab
   test3 = window.open('http://' + inputvalue, "test3");
   //Opens https non www version in new tab
   test4 = window.open('https://' + inputvalue, "test4");
   //Submits a search in new window showing main version indexed in Google
   test5 = window.open('http://google.com/search?q=' + 'site:' + inputvalue, "test5");
 });
});
```

Comment: perhaps it's because jsfiddle is `https` and you're opening `http`

Comment: Thanks Jaromanda, I actually misinterpreted what you meant, which is I was trying to essentially open an unsecure frame in a secure window. I also noticed that the <body> tag was missing from the html portion. Adding that and then accessing jsfiddle from non ssl URL worked. New version is 27. Mods may close this submission (first post to stack and didn't see option to close my own post)